# jqGrid column resizing issue

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid 4.6.0 and displaying a fairly large set of data. I have set my column width in colModel as 150 for all the columns. Now when I try to change the width of a column from the UI, the header gets resized but the all the columns below are distorted. I am sharing the configurations I have done for the grid. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Configuration model:

```
var ruleTable = jQuery("#rule_table").jqGrid({
data: data,
datatype: 'local',
colNames: settings.parameters,
colModel: settings.colModel,
height: 350,
width: $('.tabular_format_data').width(),
shrinkToFit: false,
viewrecords: true,
gridview: true,
sortorder: "desc",
rowNum: settings.rowNum,
rowList: settings.rowList,
loadComplete: function (data) {
    highlightColumnFields();    
},
'cellEdit': true,
'cellsubmit' : 'clientArray',
editurl: 'clientArray'
});
```

where colModel is:

```
var createColModel = function (data) {
    var colModel = [];
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        if (!(value instanceof Object)) {
            var obj = {};
            obj.align = 'center';
            obj.sortable = false;
            obj.name = key;
            obj.index = key;
            obj.width = 150;
            obj.sortable = true;

            if (obj.name === "clientClassification" || obj.name === "subCategory2" || obj.name === "clientResolutionTime") { 
                obj.editable = true;
                if (obj.name === "clientClassification") {
                    obj.edittype = "select";
                    obj.formatter = "select";
                    obj.editoptions = {value: SMCClassification};
                }
            }

            colModel.push(obj);
        }
    });

    return colModel;
};
```

Comment: Could you provide the demo which reproduces the code? Do you have the names of columns which contains special characters like space, comma, dot and so on? If such characters can exist then I'd recommend you to try to reproduce the problem using [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). You can use `https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css`, `https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js` and `https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js` for the quick test.

Comment: During the test with free jqGrid you can try to include `cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true }, autoResizing: { compact: true }, autoresizeOnLoad: true`. It will resize the columns on the minimal width based on the content of the columns directly after loading of the grid. It could save the place on the page and could make the usage of the grid more comfortable. You can try to use `height: "auto"` additionally. Then the height will be calculated based on `rowNum` value and the number of displayed rows (it can be less as `rowNum`). You can temporary comment `highlightColumnFields` for a test only

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Oleg. My column names are something like 'Ticket Complexity - Client Classification', 'Time taken to solve (minutes) - Client Touch time' which do contain special characters as you mentioned. Is this the reason for the issue that I am facing?

Comment: I have created another grid whose column names also contains some special characters but that grid works perfectly fine. The column resizing there does not result in distorted grid. So maybe the issue here is something different.

Comment: Hey I got something. The issue is observed on Mozilla firefox. It works perfectly fine on google chrome. I have firefox version 36.0.4. Any idea why is that so?

Comment: Space - is special character which is not allowed be used in `id` in HTML5, bracket is special character too. The id should be alpha-numeric with underscore only. `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ` should be not used. **You should provide the demo which reproduce the problem.** I suggested you to try [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). Is the problem the same?

Comment: I couldn't use free jqGrid but i tried to create a jsfiddle for it. But its working there somehow and not in my application. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CzVVK/1528/

Comment: Sorry, but the demo don't work at all. Even the data which you included is buggy: two items contains *the same* data, but what is about unique rowid? (`"id": "5234239sdfsdfdsf4234"`)

Comment: My bad.. Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p_gupta/3hm04mhg/. The ("id": "5234239sdfsdfdsf4234")  you mentioned is not used anywhere in the grid, that is just an extra parameter. Also, even if the data contains duplicate items, that shouldn't matter. It's just a dummy data used to create the grid. Somehow, in fiddle the columns are getting resized properly so I don't know how do I proceed with this issue. For time being, I have disabled column resizing to proceed further.

Comment: I see no resizing problems in the demo with the test data which you included. I asked you to the demo **which reproduces the problem** because I supposed that the problem exist only with specific data. Some common remarks about your code: **you should assign `id` attribute to the items of the input data**. I strictly recommend you to replace `highlightColumnFields` to `callattr` which set class on the cell based on contains of other columns. It will work **much more effective** as your current code especially in case of large number of rows and columns. I recommend you to use `height: "auto"`

Comment: It's not good to set `settings.rowNum = data.length;` which means the same as `settings.rowNum: 10000`. It's better to use *local* paging of data and specify in the `rowNum` the number of rows in the page which you want to display. I don't recommend to set `index` in `colModel`, remove `sortable = true`. Instead of setting **the same** values in `colModel` you should use `cmTemplate` like `cmTemplate: {align: 'center', width: 100, sortable: false}`. The code of `createColModel` can be reduced.

Comment: Updated fiddle with actual data set and height: "auto". http://jsfiddle.net/3hm04mhg/1/. I had purposely not set height as auto because the table gets too big and the user has to go to the bottom of table to get the horizontal scroll. Yes, in fiddle the resizing is working absolutely fine with exactly the same code. I don't understand how is that happening and I am not even able to attach screenshots here as I don't have enough credits they say

Comment: I'll also try to explore the callattr which you mentioned. I had to set rowNum to entire data set because our client is against paging of data. They want the entire data set upfront and are not comfortable with paging.

Comment: Just add `pager: "#pager"` or `toppager: true` (or both) and replace `rowNum: settings.rowNum` with `rowNum: 20` for example. Look at the following grid for example: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/3hm04mhg/4/embedded/result/ where I removed `width` option too and added `filterToolbar` which can be additionally customized. It will be good displayed in web browser window and the user can good see the results, use paging annd to filter the results.

Comment: This too doesn't work for me. It's getting time consuming now. I think I will stick to keeping resizable property to false. I can see no other option to this. Thanks @Oleg for all the help that you provided. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome! In any way the current implementation of `highlightColumnFields` is the bottleneck of your code. You can just temporary comment it and you will see that the grid will work **much more quickly**. If you would use `cellattr` instead of `highlightColumnFields` then you will have *the same* quick grid like with the commented `highlightColumnFields`. If you will later create the demo which reproduces your *original problem with resizing of columns* you can post new comment to me.

Comment: Surely I will. Yes I tried to run the code after commenting out the highlightColumnFields. Couldn't notice much of a difference but yes I will definitely try using cellattr if it helps in code optimization. Thanks once again

Comment: @Oleg I was able to fix this issue of column resizing in firefox. Acually, there was a CSS issue. The container which contained the table had a class applied which was used by other table. This class had its <td> set max-width: 200, and that is why, the column headers were getting resized and the cells were not. Also, the 'max-width' property for table is ignored by google chrome. So it seemed to work on google chrome and looked like an issue on firefox.

Comment: It's good news! Congratulation!